# How can I install certificate for "Visual studio emulator for android"'s emulator?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I am working on a **Xamarin Form** that need to call `httpclient` to consume company's internal https REST api.

Unfortunately, it return with this error

```
Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bypass certification validation you can:

In Android Build options choose

```
HttpClient Implementation: AndroidClientHandler
SSL/TLS implementation: Default (Native TLS 1.2+)
```

In MainActivity.cs add this

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, cert, chain, errors) => true;
```

In the Httpclient init change this

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

To

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler());
```

Comment: Hi Bruno, I can't find the Android build option. Is this available in xamarin form, visual studio 2017?

Comment: Yes, it is. Right Click android solution, and options

Comment: Thanks bruno, i was able to find it with "Right click on android solution >> Properties >> Android Options >> Advanced" It is working fine by implementing your suggestion. thanks again !

Comment: Hi DEN, glad I could help!

Comment: Do not leave this in production code! It disables certificate chain validation and enables man-in-the-middle attacks. For development that can be handy (using Fiddler to see what's going on) but in production you wouldn't want a third party sniffing your traffic.