# SSLHandshakeException CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I try to connect from my `Xamarin application` which runs on `Android emulator` to my `rest api service` runs on pc installed as windows service on `https://localhost:5001`. When i try to connect to `api` i get following long error. I've tried to access service from `Xamarin` like below, as i read that `pc ip` is always `10.0.2.2`. WHat can i do to access correctly my `service`?

```
https://10.0.2.2:5001/api/Car/GetModelName
```

**Error:**

```
{Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0 
  at Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnectionInvoker.Connect () [0x0000a] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0007d] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2476 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x0012e] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002d0] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506 
  at Appi.Application.Services.WebApiService.WebApiService.IsUserExist (Appi.DomainLayer.Models.User.User user) [0x000bd] in C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Dzwonnik_combined\Solution1\Appi.Application\Services\WebApiService\WebAPIService.cs:29 
  at MobileAppXamarinForms.ViewModels.Login.LoginViewModel.LogIn () [0x00057] in C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Dzwonnik_combined\Solution1\MobileAppXamarinForms\ViewModels\Login\LoginViewModel.cs:48 
  --- End of managed Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException stack trace ---
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:229)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:661)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:539)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:208)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:404)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    ... 24 more
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The certificate you are using on your service is not trusted by the Android device.  You need to install the CA certificate on the simulator or disable certificate checking in your application when connecting to your service.

Check out [Dev Blogs from Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/cleartext-http-android-network-security/)

There is also a related [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509097/installing-ca-certificate-on-android-in-system-context) post that might be helpful.

To install the certificate on the emulator

```
emulator -avd <avd_name_here> -writable-system

adb root
adb shell remount
adb push <cert_filename> /system/etc/security/cacerts
adb shell "chmod 664 /system/etc/security/cacerts/<cert_filename>"

adb reboot
```

If you read the post it is in the original query, there are problems with this, so it may be better to disable SSL checking for connections to your test host.  See the stackoverflow answer.

Here is another link that shows how to disable all SSL checking from your build
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597401/how-can-i-install-certificate-for-visual-studio-emulator-for-androids-emulato)

Comment: that unfortunetly doesn't help. There is nothing about how to install certificate.